# Unable to Build and Run Android App after adding google play service com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi am using Android map and I have used
com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0. After adding this service
,unable to run app. It gives the error message as shown in the below -

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Error:Registry editing has been disabled by your administrator.
Error:Registry editing has been disabled by your administrator.
Error:Registry editing has been disabled by your administrator.
Information:3 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: "See complete output in console"...There you can see the what are the errors

Comment: Kindly past the full error log.

Comment: Hi selva there is no log only have Message Gradle Build which return 3 errors

Comment: Not syncing Gradle also return error message which are given in my question.